# Trying to plot a function but getting only dots instead?

Tags: matlab, plot

This is my first assignment that needs MatLab so I'm just learning how to use it.
As my question states, there must be something wrong in my code that makes points instead of a function that looks similar to a square root function.

```
h=0.1;
tf=1;
samples = round(tf/h+1);
x = ones (samples, 1);
y = zeros (samples, 1); 
y_true = zeros (samples, 1); 
hold on;
for n=1: samples ;
   t=(n-1)/10 +h;
   y_true = 1-exp (-t); 
   plot (t,y_true);
end;   
hold off;
```

The values for t are `0`, `0.1`, `0.2`, `0.3` and so on until `1`. Just before posting this question I discovered what `hold()` is for, because before that I would get just a point in the middle. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can plot all the points at the same time:

```
% Parameters
h=0.1;
tf=1;

% Process
samples = round(tf/h+1);
x = ones (samples, 1);
y = zeros (samples, 1); 
y_true = zeros (samples, 1); 
n = 1:samples;
t = (n-1)./10+h;
y_true = 1-exp(-t); 

% Plot
figure
plot(t,y_true,'b-*');
```

[image]

Comment: Oh thanks. In the example my professor showed us he used the function 'for'. I'd like to know how he did it. Can you help me?

Comment: I'll try to ask a better question: Why is it that if I try using 'for' I get only points but in the form you wrote I get a line?

Comment: When you use the `for` loop, you use the function `plot` for only one point. Thus, you plot one point in each iteration. On the other hand, when you use the function `plot` to depict all the points at the same time. The function `plot` interpolates the given points to show a smoother line.

Answer (score 0):

From this code it's clear you meant to build a vector with all the points:

```
x = ones(samples, 1);
y = zeros(samples, 1); 
y_true = zeros(samples, 1);
```

To do that, you can either use a vector calculation, like tashuhka showed, or simply store one element each time through the for loop.  You do that with subscripting:

```
for n= 1:samples
   t(n) = (n-1)/10 + h;
   y_true(n) = 1-exp(-t); 
end
```

Now you can plot the entire vector in one step, outside the for loop.

Final code:

```
h=0.1;
tf=1;
samples = round(tf/h+1);
x = ones(samples, 1);
y_true = zeros(samples, 1); 
for n = 1:samples
   t(n) = (n-1)/10 +h;
   y_true(n) = 1-exp(-t); 
end
plot(t, y_true);
```